# ¿Por qué al obtener caracteres de un string e imprimirlos, muestra otro valor distinto al que es?

Tags: c#, string

Estoy realizando una `función` en `c#` la cual funciona con horas y minutos, tengo una `variable` en la cual se almacena el `string` de la hora en el siguiente formato: **`00:00:00`**, para después formatearla y quitarle los dos puntos **`:`**, por lo cual el resultado sería **`000000`**.

De esta cadena resultante, obtengo por medio de `índices` los dos números de la hora y los dos números de los minutos, por ejemplo:

> Variable[0]

Pero al imprimirlos, muestra un valor totalmente diferente, aquí anexó `código`:

Reemplazo los puntos por nada, para ejemplo, esta variable contiene **`03:05:00`**.

> string numero_hora = hora_bloqueo.Replace(":", "");

Aquí espero ver impreso **`03`**, pero imprime **`99`**

> Console.WriteLine(numero_hora[0] + numero_hora[1]);// Imprime 99

Aquí imprime correctamente el valor **`03`** pero solamente volviendo a convertir a `string` lo que se supone ya es un `string`.

> Console.WriteLine(numero_hora[0].ToString() + numero_hora[1].ToString());//Imprime 03

Y de igual forma pasa con los minutos, pero imprime otro valor distinto. Lo que quiero saber es el

> **¿Por qué sucede eso? si originalmente es un `string` del que obtengo los valores.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que `numero_hora[0] + numero_hora[1]` te esta devolviendo el código numérico de cada carácter, es decir, el `0` en Unicode es 48 y el `3` es 51 que sumados devuelven `99`.

Cuando accedes a un elemento de un string mediante índice `numero_hora[0]` te devuelve un tipo de dato char (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char) que es de tipo numérico y no es un string y por tanto, al sumarlos devuelven un número.

Prueba en su lugar con el método `Substring`:

```
Console.WriteLine(numero_hora.Substring(0, 2));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo. Tienes razón obtiene el valor del `unicode`, se me había hecho extraño ese comportamiento.

Answer (score 1):

Si de un **objeto** **DateTime** deseas obtener las horas, puedes hacer esto:

```
var horas = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh");
```

Aquí guardamos en la **variable horas** solamente la parte que representa las horas de la fecha actual.

También puedes hacer esto:

```
var horas = DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString();
```

Igualmente obtenemos las horas de un **objeto** **DateTime**, pero esta vez a través de la **propiedad Hour**.

En el caso de los minutos podemos hacer lo siguiente:

```
var minutos = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm");
```

Guardamos en la **variable minutos** la parte de la fecha que corresponde a los minutos.

También podemos de esta forma:

```
var minutos = DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString();
```

Accedemos a los minutos del **objeto** **DateTime** a través de la **propiedad Minute**.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, me es útil tu respuesta.